# Android Studio's menu bar is unreadible

Tags: android, android-studio, i3

Android Studio in my i3 window manager doesn't show the menubar text. The buttons are still interactable but I can't read them.

[image]

[My dotfiles](https://github.com/danhab99/dotfiles)

Screenfetch:

```
 dan@dan-ms7d09
 OS: Manjaro 21.1.5 Pahvo
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.70-1-MANJARO
 Uptime: 21m
 Packages: 1391
 Shell: zsh 5.8
 Resolution: 5760x1080
 DE: GNOME
 WM: i3
 GTK Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Adwaita
 Font: Cantarell 11
 Disk: 265G / 954G (30%)
 CPU: Intel Core i9-10850K @ 20x 5.2GHz [50.0°C]
 GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
 RAM: 5443MiB / 32003MiB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the studio settings, and then maybe try installing dconf or tweaks to see if you can alter the design of i3.

Some window managers and apps don't like to work together as part of an aesthetic choice by the devs.

You can always try to hold alt + the letter that is underlined in the menu to get to the choices, but as I understand it, you can already interact with them, just not see them.

This seems to be a broken theme, though. If it is not a part of a purposeful decision, then you may have to put in a bug report.